# WiX - VS Schema and Visual Studio 2019

Tags: wix, visual-studio-2019, wix3.11

I'm having trouble upgrading a setup project that referenced Visual Studio 2017 and now I want to reference Visual Studio 2019.

Product.wxs references the following properties (as documented [here](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixvsextension.html)):

```
VS2019_IDE_VCSHARP_PROJECTSYSTEM_INSTALLED
VS2019_EXTENSIONS_DIR
```

When building the setup I get the following error:

```
Unresolved reference to symbol 'Property:VS2019_IDE_VCSHARP_PROJECTSYSTEM_INSTALLED' in section 'Product:*'.
Unresolved reference to symbol 'Property:VS2019_EXTENSIONS_DIR' in section 'Product:*'.
```

This worked perfectly before using the corresponding Visual Studio 2017 properties:

```
VS2017_IDE_VCSHARP_PROJECTSYSTEM_INSTALLED
VS2017_EXTENSIONS_DIR
```

What am I missing here?

PS:

- Wix Toolset version is 3.11.1.2318.
- Wix Toolset Visual Studio 2019
  Extension is 1.0.0.4.

Thanks.

Comment: Never tried this, maybe have a look at [github.com and some sample hits](https://github.com/search?q=VS2019_EXTENSIONS_DIR&type=Code). And maybe hit the [bug tracker](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues) to see if there is anything there or add a bug report. **Bob Arnson** will probably show up and save the day. Or **Chris Painter** - one of the sample hits on github is his. Can't look at it right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the latest prerelease developer build of WiX 3.14 found at https://wixtoolset.org/releases/development/  for those properties to exist.

The 2019 `extension` only integrates WiX with VS 2019.   The `extensions` such as VS, Util, UI, SQL and so on are part of WiX proper.  Confusing I know.

Comment: Saved the day ;-).