# Using $(env.VCINSTALLDIR) fails in candle.exe with CNDL0150

Tags: wix, environment-variables, visual-studio-2019

I need to use an environment variable.

The CMD Prompt shows the following content

`VCINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\`

Now I try to use this

```
  <Merge Id='VC_CRT_x86' 
     Language='0' 
     SourceFile='$(env.VCINSTALLDIR)\Redist\MSVC\14.16.27012\MergeModules\Microsoft_VC141_CRT_x86.msm'  
     DiskId='1' 
  />
```

But I get the message

```
error CNDL0150: Undefined preprocessor variable '$(env.VCINSTALLDIR)'.
```

Using the full path works.

I compile from within the VS-2019 environment.

EDIT: When I use a simple CMD window and I use Candle.exe from there. Everything works. It seams that the environment variables are not passed within VS-2019.

EDIT2: Using `devenv.exe /build release mywxsproject.sln` works too!

Comment: Heads-up on this issue: [WiX 3.14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589954/wix-vs-schema-and-visual-studio-2019/57593964#57593964) - [WixVSExtension](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixvsextension.html). Not the same, but since you use VS2019.

Answer (score 1):

***UPDATE***: First a couple of links on the issue of environment variables and running processes:

- [Changing environment variables for running processes?](https://superuser.com/questions/1141461/how-to-change-environment-variable-to-running-process-in-windows)
- [Is there a command to refresh environment variables from the command prompt in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171588/is-there-a-command-to-refresh-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt-in-w)

---

***cmd.exe***: You are probably doing **`"set"`** from a **`Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt`** as opposed to doing **`"set"`** from a regular **`cmd.exe`** **`=>`** this yields a false list of what are actual environment variables.

***Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt***: The **`Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt`** is essentially [a batch file](https://github.com/ojdkbuild/tools_toolchain_vs2017bt/blob/ee20a12c95b6a8b5942bf66a48424f61d560e938/Common7/Tools/VsDevCmd.bat) which launches **`cmd.exe`** with a number of developer tweaks. How this all works I have no idea, but that's the essence. We may need to summon [**`Mr. Heath Stewart`**](https://twitter.com/mrhestew) to get to the bottom of this?

***WiX Variables***: I did a smoke test and the **`$(env.MY_VALUE_HERE)`** construct should resolve if the environment variable is set from the environment variable applet:

```
rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
```

Press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>, tap <kbd>R</kbd>, paste the above and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

***Solutions***: In the realm of fixes I am not sure what to suggest since I don't know what the purpose is in detail. I am suspecing you want everything to "run out of the box", but I would simply copy all the merge modules you need to the release area where you assemble your setup:

Something like this:

- **`$(env.VCINSTALLDIR)\Redist\MSVC\14.16.27012\MergeModules\Microsoft_VC141_CRT_x86.msm`**
- **`\\Releases\Common\MergeModules\Microsoft_VC141_CRT_x86.msm`**

Comment: I have to disagree. If I start a batch file from within the build process in VS-2019, the required variables are there. I have a post and pre build processthat uses them successfully. Also using it pure from the command line works, but only the build process inside VS-2019 fails.See new note:

Comment: Did you try WiX 3.14?

Comment: No. Currently I have no time to switch.

Comment: I suppose you could try to add it as a "real" environment variable? Not that clean (sort of an override - visual studio might even complain?), but I guess it could work for now? I really would propose to put all merge modules on a shared UNC path though - since they can be included in any package that way and it gives you a "preserved library" of merge modules?