# WiX project 'incompatible' in VS2019

Tags: wix, visual-studio-2019

worked-in: VS2017
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.5.0
WiX Toolset Visual Studio Extension version 1.0.0.4
Microsoft Windows 10 Pro Version 10.0.17763 Build 17763

Recently installed VS2019 community. wixprog opens with "incompatible’. I have Wix extension installed.

I've contacted the VS2019 developers and they determined it's a WiX problem.

Getting the following erros:

> An error occurred in '[Unknown]' while attempting to open 'eesPhotographyProperties.wxs'

File Path: D:\Software\CSharp\SetupEesPhotography\SetupEesPhotography\eesPhotographyProperties.wxs

Frame Model: VSFM_MdiChild

Error Code: 0x80004005

> An error occurred in '[Unknown]' while attempting to open 'Product.wxs'

File Path: D:\Software\CSharp\SetupEesPhotography\SetupEesPhotography\Product.wxs

Frame Model: VSFM_MdiChild

Error Code: 0x80004005

Comment: [Maybe check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589954/wix-vs-schema-and-visual-studio-2019). Also reboot and try again. If all fails: Install VS2017 on virtual? [There is a minimal installation option described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60760014/129130) (the minimal components you need to install to get WiX projects to compile with Visual Studio).

Comment: I installed the Wix development build, and I'm getting the same errors.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems like a problem for the developers to solve and won't be fixed by the community. No answers in a year seems to support this.